# How to prove this expression

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

How to prove that:

$P\left(A,B \mid C\right) = P\left(A \mid B,C\right) \cdot P\left(B \mid C\right)$ where $A,B,C$ are all events.

Comment: By "A,B" you mean intersection $\;A\cap B\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio, yes conjoint probability

Comment: @DonAntonio Is P(A,(B|C))=P((A,B)|C) ?

Comment: For me, $\;A, (B\,|\,C)=A\cap(B\,|\,C)\;$ , and the probability of this would be the conjoint probability of two events, *not* a conditional one, so I'm going to go with no: it's not the same.

Comment: So if we get such P(A, B | C) without parenthesis, How can we should treat it? conjoint or conditional?

Comment: @Be Conditional, of course. Say it in english outloud, maybe it'll make more sense: that is the conditional probability of ($\;A\;$ and $\;B\;$) assuming $\;C\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio FYI, the objects $(B\mid C)$ and $A\cap(B\mid C)$ simply do not exist. When the OP mentions P(A,(B|C)), the useful thing to do is to mention that (B|C) is absurd.

Comment: @Did Thanks. I wasn't sure of the notation of the OP from the beginning. I thought  the probability of $\;A\cap (B\,|\,C)\;$ could perhaps mean the probability of event $\;A\;$ **and also**  (event $\;B\;$ assuming $\;C\;$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very hand-wavy way is to use the definition of conditional probability to note $P(A,B) = P(A \mid C) \cdot P(B)$ for any given probability distribution $P$. Then, note that the expression you want to prove is just the same thing but with each term conditioned on $C$. This conditional distribution $P(\cdot \mid C)$ is just another distribution, so we immediately arrive at the desired equality.

---

The direct way is to just write out all the conditional probabilities.

\begin{align}
P(A,B \mid C) &= \frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(C)}\\
P(A \mid B,C) &= \frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(B,C)}\\
P(B \mid C) &= \frac{P(B,C)}{P(C)}.
\end{align}
Combining everything gives the desired equality.

Comment: Is  P(A,(B|C))=P((A,B)|C) ?

Comment: @BetterEnglish I don't think $P(A,(B \mid C))$ is well-defined.

Comment: @BetterEnglish $(B|C)$ cannot be identified with any event. This in contrast with $A,B,C$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that $$P(A, B, C, \ldots \mid X, Y, Z, \dots) = \frac{P(A, B, C, \ldots, X, Y, Z, \dots)}{P\left(X, Y, Z, \dots\right)}$$

for any number of $A,B,C,\ldots$ and $X,Y,Z,\ldots$ we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
P\left(A \mid B,C\right) \cdot P\left(B \mid C\right) &= \frac{P\left(A,B,C\right)}{P\left(B,C\right)} \cdot \frac{P\left(B, C\right)}{P\left(C\right)} \\
&= \frac{P\left(A,B,C\right)}{P\left(C\right)} \\
&= P\left(A,B \mid C\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Simply definition (or theorem, it depends on how you saw it)

$$P(A\,|\,B\cap C)\cdot P(B\,|\,C)=\require{cancel}\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{\require{cance} \cancel{P(B\cap C)}}\cdot \frac{\cancel{P(B\cap C)}}{P(C)}=$$

$$=\frac{P(A\cap B\cap C)}{P(C)}=P(A\cap B\,|\,C)$$